# GreenDao load by index

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator

I have an Entity with a composite key. Following the suggestion from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/greendao/nL1GP35k9Pc/ygpA66lhUxwJ), i have the following code in my DaoGenerator which creates an index base on two `long` properties.

```
Entity transaction = schema.addEntity("TransactionDb");
transaction.addIdProperty().primaryKey();
Property msb = transaction.addLongProperty("msb").notNull().getProperty();
Property lsb = transaction.addLongProperty("lsb").notNull().getProperty();
Index transactionIndexUnique = new Index();
transactionIndexUnique.addProperty(msb);
transactionIndexUnique.addProperty(lsb);
transactionIndexUnique.makeUnique();
transaction.addIndex(transactionIndexUnique);
transaction.addStringProperty("request");
transaction.addIntProperty("flag").notNull();
```

How can i retrieve an entity by its index? I am expecting something along the line of `mDaoSession.getTransactionDbDao().loadByIndex()` but there is no such method.